# Numpy equivalent of pd.dataframe.shift in lambda

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, lambda, rolling-computation

I'd like to apply a lambda to a rolling dataframe (*this is what I want*):

```
window_size = 10
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': np.random.rand(100), 'B': np.random.rand(100)+1})
def delta(x, d: int):
  return x - x.shift(d)  # I need shift here, not roll. That is, the beginning elements SHOULD be NaN

ck = lambda x: (x.min()-x.values[-1]) if delta(x.mean(),2*window_size) <= 0.05 * x.values[0] \
          else (-1)*delta(x,int(window_size/2.0))
a2 = df['A'].shift(1).rolling(2*window_size).apply(ck)
```

It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1913, in apply
    return super().apply(
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1390, in apply
    return self._apply(
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 615, in _apply
    return self._apply_blockwise(homogeneous_func, name, numeric_only)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 468, in _apply_blockwise
    return self._apply_series(homogeneous_func, name)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 452, in _apply_series
    result = homogeneous_func(values)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 610, in homogeneous_func
    result = calc(values)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 607, in calc
    return func(x, start, end, min_periods, *numba_args)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1417, in apply_func
    return window_func(values, begin, end, min_periods)
  File "pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.pyx", line 1423, in pandas._libs.window.aggregations.roll_apply
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in delta
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

I then update the `delta` function:  (**This one has no error, but the result is incorrect.**)

```
def delta(x, d: int):
  return x - np.roll(x,d)
```

It runs w/o any error. However, the result is not correct for `a2[:2*window_size]` since the function `delta` did not return `np.NaN` when it should have returned `np.NaN`. (`roll` returns `[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]` while I expect `shift` to return `[nan, nan, nan, 1, 2]`)

I then manually set certain part of `x` to be `np.NaN` in the `delta` function

```
def delta(x, d: int):
  x[-d:] = np.NaN # also tried x.values[-d:] = np.nan, but did not work either
  return x - np.roll(x,d)
```

However it returned this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1913, in apply
    return super().apply(
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1390, in apply
    return self._apply(
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 615, in _apply
    return self._apply_blockwise(homogeneous_func, name, numeric_only)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 468, in _apply_blockwise
    return self._apply_series(homogeneous_func, name)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 452, in _apply_series
    result = homogeneous_func(values)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 610, in homogeneous_func
    result = calc(values)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 607, in calc
    return func(x, start, end, min_periods, *numba_args)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1417, in apply_func
    return window_func(values, begin, end, min_periods)
  File "pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.pyx", line 1423, in pandas._libs.window.aggregations.roll_apply
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in delta
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

How can I resolve this problem?  (BTW, I learnt rolling+lambda from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954560/pandas-rolling-apply-custom))

**Update**: by the `delta` function, I want the diff between `df.rolling().mean()` and `df.rolling().mean().shift()`. However, in the lambda `ck` above, `x.mean()` turns into a scalar, and `shift`/`roll` does not work on it. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it's `delta(x.mean(),2*window_size)` after `if` statement ? Cause `x.mean()` is a float

Comment: @HMH1013 No wonder I got `numpy.float64` error. Yes, I'd like to compute the diff of `x.mean()` and `x.mean().shift()`.  `df.rolling().mean()` returns a sequence and `df.rolling().mean().shift` is also a sequence I want their diff. I now know where the error comes from (`x.mean()` is a scalar not a sequence), but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: as an aside, you shouldn't even be using a lambda expression here. Just use a function definition statement if you are going to assign the result of a lambda expression to a variable. given the complexity here, you probably want to do it anyway